# Edit secpol.msc programmatically?

Tags: c#, windows-server-2008, local-security-policy

Is there a way to edit the settings from secpol.msc programmatically?

I am looking for something similar to this:

```
        ManagementScope scope = new ManagementScope("root\\rsop\\user\\" + user.User.Value.Replace('-', '_'));
        ObjectQuery query = new ObjectQuery("Select * from RSOP_PolicySetting");
        ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(scope, query);
```

Is root\secpol\... an option?

Comment: I found the solution. Reading from the secedit.exe export is perfect: https://gist.github.com/jkingry/421802

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. Reading from the secedit export is perfect: https://gist.github.com/jkingry/421802